# File has rows , first 2 line become one line and next 2 lines one line

Tags: bash, shell

I have file it contains row like below

```sh
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H 
K
```

required out put :

```sh
A B
B C
D E
F G
H K
```

in Linux bash.

Comment: please show your attempt in question

Comment: Please explain the special logic for your requirement that `B` is printed twice, but none of the others are.  Should that only happen for lines containing `B`?  Or should it only happen for the second line?  Or should it only happen when encountering a `C`?  Or do you need a random number generator that will randomly duplicate a line?  Or do you parse the entire input and if there's an odd number of lines you duplicate the second one?  Or something else?

Comment: @Narendra : You need to post your code for this, or explain at which point you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR%2 { printf "%s",$0 } !(NR%2) { printf "%s\n",$0 }' file
```

If modulus of the record number is 1 then print the line without a line feed, otherwise print the line with a line feed.